# Cannot resolve symbol 'page'

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

I'm starting a new project with maven and Java and When I add:

```
 public DesbloqueioSaldo(AppiumDriver<RemoteWebElement> driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), page:this);
}
```

I receive this message:
Not a statement

That project is to automate mobile test with Appium and Java.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "page:this" to "this" and then try.